# Initialize a const array with random numbers

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

I have been tasked to calculate the time it takes for my PC to do a matrix multiplication with dimensions 2048x2048 (and get 10 samples) and I was given the following function

```
/*
 * matrixMult - Matrix multiplication
 */
void matrixMult(float *const C, /* output matrix */
float const *const A, /* first matrix */
float const *const B, /* second matrix */
int const n) { /* number of rows/cols */
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { /* rows */
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { /* cols */
      /* initialize output value */
      C[sub2ind(i, j, n)] = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) { /* accumulate products */
        C[sub2ind(i, j, n)] += A[sub2ind(i, k, n)] * B[sub2ind(k, j, n)];
      }
    }
  }
} // end function 'matrixMult'
```

and this to use in my main

```
double time = 0.0;
/* compute matrix multiplication */
for (int it = 0; it < MAX_ITER; it++) {
  gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
  matrixMult( C, A, B, n );
  gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
  time = ( (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000.0 + /* sec to ms */
      (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000.0 ); /* us to ms */
  fprintf("Iter: %d Time: %f\n", it, time);
}
```

So what I have to do is initialize the arrays A and B with random values?
I can't think of a way.
This is what I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define sub2ind(i,j,n) (j) +(i)*(n)
float *const A, *const B, *const C;

void matrixMult(float *const C, /* output matrix */
float const *const A, /* first matrix */
float const *const B, /* second matrix */
int const n);

int main() {
  int n = 2048;
  double time = 0.0;
  struct timeval start, end;
  /* compute matrix multiplication */
  for (int it = 0; it < 10; it++) {
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    matrixMult(C, A, B, n);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    time = ((end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000.0 + /* sec to ms */
    (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000.0); /* us to ms */
    fprintf("Iter: %d Time: %f\n", it + 1, time);
  }
  return 0;
}

/*
 * matrixMult - Matrix multiplication
 */
void matrixMult(float *const C, /* output matrix */
    float const *const A, /* first matrix */
    float const *const B, /* second matrix */
    int const n) { /* number of rows/cols */
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { /* rows */
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { /* cols */
      /* initialize output value */
      C[sub2ind(i, j, n)] = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) { /* accumulate products */
        C[sub2ind(i, j, n)] += A[sub2ind(i, k, n)] * B[sub2ind(k, j, n)];
      }
    }
  }
} // end function 'matrixMult'
```

Comment: Please learn to format C code properly. This will serve not only the readers of your code, but yourself as well.

Comment: Will do,thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Note that in order to check or time a matrix multiplication algorithm, randomness of the values is not necessary.

Comment: You can use the `edit` button below your question to fix the broken formatting. Proper indentation is important.

Comment: I thought that the randomnsess wouldn't interfere with the time but these were the instructions.

Comment: Why do you want to have `const` arrays? `const` in a function parameter list does not mean you must provide a `const` variable. BTW: After fixing your formatting you might get more attention. Only few people want to read such a badly readable code.

Comment: I will try and modify it. That's how the code was given to us as a task

Comment: @mitousis Rather than "learn to format C code properly", learn how to use an auto formatter.  It will speed up coding and improve presentation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Disagree with "in order to check or time a matrix multiplication algorithm, randomness of the values is not necessary."  C does not specify constant time for `*` nor does hardware FP always perform in constant time.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I disagree with your comment. Non-random does not mean constant. And if you want to care about hardware behavior, using random numbers is probably not the right idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float *const A, *const B, *const C;` are global pointers.  Each, at program start, are given a value 0, a *null pointer*.  Since they are `const`, the pointer cannot change.  We are stuck.

---

Instead, do not make them `const` - there is no need for that.  In `main()`, allocate memory and values before the test.

Note that `matrixMult()` uses a pointer to `float` rather than a more 2D like type.  We can take advantage of that when first assigning `A, B`.

```
float *A, *B, *C;

int main() {
   ...
   A = malloc(sizeof A[0] * n * n);
   B = malloc(sizeof B[0] * n * n);

   // Zero fill product array in case multiplication is in error.
   // Assigning simplifies debugging.
   C = calloc((size_t)n * n, sizeof C[0]);  

   // If out-of-memory ...
   if (A == NULL || B == NULL || C == NULL) {
     // Might as well exit code here with an error message
   }

   // Fill A[], B[] with something interesting.
   for (size_t i = 0; i < (size_t)n * n; i)) {
     A[i] = rand();
     B[i] = rand();
   }
   
   // Test code here.
  ... 

   // Clean up
   free(A); A = NULL;
   free(B); B = NULL;
   free(C); C = NULL;
}
```

---

Notes: `#define sub2ind(i,j,n) (j) +(i)*(n)` risks precedence issues.  Better as `#define sub2ind(i,j,n) ((j) +(i)*(n))`.  Even better as `#define sub2ind(i,j,n) (j) +(size_t)(i)*(n)` to insure `size_t` math as `int` math is more likely will to overflow.

Answer (score -1):

I would reccoment for you to check out the standard function rand()

> int rand( void )

It returns with a random intiger between 0 to RAND_MAX.

Comment: And how do I use it ? In a loop ? E.g. A[i]=rand() outside or inside the main?